# Swagger api-docs and narrowing results to chosen tags

Tags: swagger, springfox

I have API exposed as Swagger v2 and Swagger-UI running. When I request `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs` I get all available endpoints and definitions, but instead I would like to narrow results to only few tags like: admin-controller, user-controller.

Is it possible an how to achieve that?

Comment: What framework do you use - Springfox (Java), Swashbuckle (.NET), something else?

Comment: I use Springfox but I have no possibility to modify API - I'm looking if exists a way of filtering data directly in http call (right now I fetch full API docs, then parse it and retrieve only endpoints and definitions related to tag).

Comment: I think you can do it using `paths()` Cf. https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#configuring-springfox